# Web Forms code behind to ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a small page in Web Forms, and I'm trying to make it ASP.NET MVC.
My Web Forms page:

```
    <div class="row">

        <div class="col-lg-12" align="center">
            <h1 class="page-header">Tour Packages</h1>
        </div>

        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-xs-6 thumb">
            <asp:LinkButton CssClass="thumbnail" runat="server" ID="link1" CommandArgument="" OnCommand="link1_Command">
                <asp:Label ID="label1" runat="server" Font-Size="X-Large" ForeColor="Blue" CssClass="StrongText" />
                <asp:Image ID="imgHome1" CssClass="img-responsive" ImageUrl="http://placehold.it/400x300" runat="server" height ="160" width = "320" />
            </asp:LinkButton>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-xs-6 thumb">
            <asp:LinkButton CssClass="thumbnail" runat="server" ID="link2" CommandArgument="" OnCommand="link1_Command">
                <asp:Label ID="label2" runat="server" Font-Size="X-Large" ForeColor="Blue" CssClass="StrongText" />
                <asp:Image ID="imgHome2" CssClass="img-responsive" ImageUrl="http://placehold.it/400x300" runat="server" height ="160" width = "320" />
            </asp:LinkButton>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-xs-6 thumb">
            <asp:LinkButton CssClass="thumbnail" runat="server" CommandArgument="" ID="link3" OnCommand="link1_Command">
                <asp:Label ID="label3" runat="server" Font-Size="X-Large" ForeColor="Blue" CssClass="StrongText" />
                <asp:Image ID="imgHome3" CssClass="img-responsive" ImageUrl="http://placehold.it/400x300" runat="server" height ="160" width = "320" />
            </asp:LinkButton>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-xs-6 thumb">
            <asp:LinkButton CssClass="thumbnail" runat="server" CommandArgument="" ID="link4" OnCommand="link1_Command">
                <asp:Label ID="label4" runat="server" Font-Size="X-Large" ForeColor="Blue" CssClass="StrongText" />
                <asp:Image ID="imgHome4" CssClass="img-responsive" ImageUrl="http://placehold.it/400x300" runat="server" height ="160" width = "320" />
            </asp:LinkButton>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-xs-6 thumb">
            <asp:LinkButton CssClass="thumbnail" runat="server" CommandArgument="" ID="link5" OnCommand="link1_Command">
                <asp:Label ID="label5" runat="server" Font-Size="X-Large" ForeColor="Blue" CssClass="StrongText" />
                <asp:Image ID="imgHome5" CssClass="img-responsive" ImageUrl="http://placehold.it/400x300" runat="server" height ="160" width = "320" />
            </asp:LinkButton>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-xs-6 thumb">
            <asp:LinkButton CssClass="thumbnail" runat="server" CommandArgument="" ID="link6" OnCommand="link1_Command">
                <asp:Label ID="label6" runat="server" Font-Size="X-Large" ForeColor="Blue" CssClass="StrongText" />
                <asp:Image ID="imgHome6" CssClass="img-responsive" ImageUrl="http://placehold.it/400x300" runat="server" height ="160" width = "320" />
            </asp:LinkButton>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-xs-6 thumb">
            <asp:LinkButton CssClass="thumbnail" runat="server" CommandArgument="" ID="link7" OnCommand="link1_Command">
                <asp:Label ID="label7" runat="server" Font-Size="X-Large" ForeColor="Blue" CssClass="StrongText" />
                <asp:Image ID="imgHome7" CssClass="img-responsive" ImageUrl="http://placehold.it/400x300" runat="server" height ="160" width = "320" />
            </asp:LinkButton>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-xs-6 thumb">
            <asp:LinkButton CssClass="thumbnail" runat="server" CommandArgument="" ID="link8" OnCommand="link1_Command">
                <asp:Label ID="label8" runat="server" Font-Size="X-Large" ForeColor="Blue" CssClass="StrongText" />
                <asp:Image ID="imgHome8" CssClass="img-responsive" ImageUrl="http://placehold.it/400x300" runat="server" height ="160" width = "320" />
            </asp:LinkButton>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Code behind

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    loadTours();
}

private void loadTours()
{
    int count = 1;
    var query = (from t in db.ToursPackages
                 select t).Take(8);

    foreach (var row in query)
    {
        if (count == 1)
        {
            imgHome1.ImageUrl = "../img/" + row.Img;
            label1.Text = row.Title;
            link1.CommandArgument = row.Id.ToString();
        }
        if (count == 2)
        {
            imgHome2.ImageUrl = "../img/" + row.Img;
            label2.Text = row.Title;
            link2.CommandArgument = row.Id.ToString();
        }
        if (count == 3)
        {
            imgHome3.ImageUrl = "../img/" + row.Img;
            label3.Text = row.Title;
            link3.CommandArgument = row.Id.ToString();
        }
        if (count == 4)
        {
            imgHome4.ImageUrl = "../img/" + row.Img;
            label4.Text = row.Title;
            link4.CommandArgument = row.Id.ToString();
        }
        if (count == 5)
        {
            imgHome5.ImageUrl = "../img/" + row.Img;
            label5.Text = row.Title;
            link5.CommandArgument = row.Id.ToString();
        }
        if (count == 6)
        {
            imgHome6.ImageUrl = "../img/" + row.Img;
            label6.Text = row.Title;
            link6.CommandArgument = row.Id.ToString();
        }
        if (count == 7)
        {
            imgHome7.ImageUrl = "../img/" + row.Img;
            label7.Text = row.Title;
            link7.CommandArgument = row.Id.ToString();
        }
        if (count == 8)
        {
            imgHome8.ImageUrl = "../img/" + row.Img;
            label8.Text = row.Title;
            link8.CommandArgument = row.Id.ToString();
        }
        count++;
    }
}
```

Here is my ToursPackage model

```
    namespace TravelAgencyMVC.Models.DB
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    public partial class ToursPackage
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public Nullable<decimal> Price { get; set; }
        public string Img { get; set; }
    }
}
```

In Web Forms I created the page loading the Labels text and the images URL from the database. I also created an "OnCommand" for my link. The problem is that I do not know how to create a ViewModel in MVC to do what I did in the Web Forms code behind.

EDIT***

I my question is... Where should I created the getToursPackageMethod() which will return a list of ToursPackages to populate my page? Also, how can I pass this list from my Controller to the page?

Comment: For a basic MVC app you need to create the Views, Controller and Model. ViewModels are optional, though it is good to use.
Note : An MVC app can also be used with existing .aspx pages.

Comment: Voting to close, too broad, you are asking a broad question about the basics of ASP.NET MVC. You will need to study some tutorials online. The nature of your problem is actually specific to you, no one knows how to exactly translate your Web Forms Code Behind implementation into an ASP.Net MVC implementation per se. If you know the basics of ASP.NET MVC you will be able to do what you need to convert the Web Forms code behind into the MVC design pattern and still maintain the same functionality.

Comment: I'm sorry, my question wasn't clear. I edited it.

Comment: What is in `getToursPackageMethod()` will go in a method in your controller class. You pass the list in the model.

Comment: @user6824563 Your question is clear, you are basically asking someone to code this for you is kind of what is going on, you are posting your Web Forms code and basically asking someone to code the ASP.NET MVC version of it for you or at least the Model part and that quickly leads to the View and Controller having to be code for you too.

Comment: @user6824563 You should at least attempt your question and post specific questions on issues that may arise.  Break down your problem into smaller questions like "How do I pass data from a controller to my razor view".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of this is going to be MVC 101, which you should read up on.

Instead of taking the time to basically rewrite this, I will tell you how to do it based on what you have into an MVC pattern. This is going to be quasi-coded, you get to fill in the specifics and use whatever you want for collections, enumerables,etc. You also don't mention if you are going to be using the Razor view engine (current) or if you are going to stick with ASPX (which is obsolete, but easier transition for you)

Now onto your question, you basically have a defined Model and the old webform page markup.

**0. You really don't need to have a *ViewModel*. Optional for this**

**1: You already have a Model**
You may want to add on to it to have the query methods in there, which is my preference.

**2: You need to have a Controller, with Actions**
What the Controller is going to do be a collection of different actions (~ pages). So we need to have an `ActionResult` to handle your request, get the data (from the model) and return it to the View.

```
public ActionResult ViewTourPackages() {
    Collection<ToursPackage> colTourPkgs = // Your DB query method here
    return View(colTourPkgs);
}
```

**3: The View. This is a direct analog of your ASPX WebForm**

You can actually right click within that above ActionResult and choose to create a view based on it. Visual Studio 2010 actually supported by the ASPX view engine to make transitions easier from the WebForms era. Newer versions will still allow you to use them, but there is no intellisense to help you out. New projects should all be done utilizing Razor for syntax.

Once you have the View created, you will see an *Inherits* attribute which should reference the Collection as your data model.

Then it becomes a simple iteration through the items in the collection. Each `item` can have its properties accessed directly. This obviously won't be valid HTML but it should give you a good start

```
foreach(TourPackage item in Model) {
    // your markup here
    <p>My image is <img src="../img/<%=item.Img%></p>
    // and so on.
    // The code behind calculations can all be done here
}
```